# Does the Java EE SDK installation prerequire Java SE SDK or JRE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, installation

I want to develop Java EE applications on Linux 64 bit. I want to install the latest linux 64 bit Java EE SDK. Do I need to install the Java SE SDK first? Or maybe only the Java SE JRE first?

Comment: Some reading if you are curious:http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java EE includes Java SE. If you install Java SE first then the Java EE installer will skip installing Java SE (since you already have it).